# Get Connection dataSource of Tabular database

Tags: sql, powershell, ssas-tabular, sql-server-2017

Using SQL2017 version 14.0.1.439. I need to change dataSource path of Connections in Tabular database with Powershell.

Here is my code:

```
$ServerName="localhost\tabular"
$loadInfo = 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($ServerName)
if ($server.name -eq $null) {
 Write-Output ("Server '{0}' not found" -f $ServerName)
 break
}
foreach ($d in $server.Databases )
{
Write-Output ( "Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB; Data Sources: {3} " -f $d.Name, $d.State, ($d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0"), $d.DataSources.Count )
}
```

My problem, that $d.DataSources.Count is always 0.

I am looking for some way to edit it with PS.

Comment: Show us the output you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be accessing the data sources through `Model.Datasources`
I can confirm that the following code returns the number of data sources for my Tabular models.

```
$ServerName="localhost\tabular"
$loadInfo = 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")

$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($ServerName)

if ($server.name -eq $null) {
 Write-Output ("Server '{0}' not found" -f $ServerName)
 break
}
foreach ($d in $server.Databases )
{
     Write-output ( "Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB; Data Sources: {3} " -f $d.Name, $d.State, ($d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0"), $d.Model.DataSources.Count )
}
```